# How to find files and directories for user and exclude NFS mount and symbolic links ot NFS mounts?

Tags: linux, bash, find

I would like to find and change user account and it's default group on local File Systems but exclude massive NFS mounts and symbolic links to those mounts.
I had tried multiple syntaxes but did not succeed -

```
find / -user dummyadm -print \( -fstype nfs -o type l \) -prune
```

Please help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is probably a better fit for [Unix.se]. Please note that [cross posting is generally frowned upon](//meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info), so you should either (1) post a new question there and delete this one, or (2) flag your question for a [moderator to migrate](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/269535).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for the `-xdev` option, or its synonym `-mount`.  This causes `find` to avoid crossing from one filesystem to another.  The symbolic links should not be an issue in any case, because `find`'s default behavior is to *not* traverse symbolic links.  This probably means you'll need to name all the filesystem roots you want to traverse, however.  For example, if both `/home` and `/tmp` are on separate (local) filesystems, then you might do

```
find / /home /tmp -xdev -user dummyadm ...
```

Alternatively, if you want to use the `-fstype` test, then you should probably combine it with `-not` instead of trying to use `-prune` with it:

```
find / -user dummyadm -not -fstype nfs ...
```